# Difference between 2 values in a row in excel formula

Tags: excel

How to get this in excel

[excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIYIj.jpg)

[image]

F column is the result column

Comment: Please clarify your question so people can understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please view the excel table,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following answer I am going to assume you only ever have two numbers in any row, but they can be in any cell along the row and they are always greater than 0.

If you just wish to find the difference between the two numbers without worrying about which number is bigger, a simple equation using maximum and minimum can be used, eg in Cell F1 you would have

```
=MAX(A1:E1)-MIN(A1:E1)
```

However, from your example, it seems more likely that you want to know the difference between the first number and the second number.
The difficulty here, is that the cells in columns B, C and D could contain either the first number, the second number, or no number! The solution is to use the following equation in Cell F1

```
=(MAX(A1:E1)-MIN(A1:E1))*IF(MAX(A1:E1)=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(0,A1:E1,-1)),-1,1)
```

This formula works as follows:

We still start off with the simple difference between the max and min, and then this is multiplied by 1 or -1 depending on which way around the numbers are.

```
MATCH(0,A1:E1,-1)
```

This part of the equation looks along the row for a 0, and assumes they are in descending order, so it will return the position of the second number.

This is then inserted into the INDEX function and checked to see if it is the same as the maximum number and the IF function returns either -1 or 1 as required.

Comment: Thank you, you save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Paste this formula on F1, then copy to F2 and F3

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:E1<>"",),0)) - LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A1:E1)
```